# Issue does not exist or you do not have permission to see it- error in jira api call

Tags: flutter, dart, jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to make a jira rest api call using dart in flutter.
I have correct api token, username and url.
while trying to make the api call, I am getting the above error.
I have followed all the instructions as mentioned by other answers in various similar questions.
While I print the response.request I am getting a link by clicking on which I am redirected correctly to a json file.

Here is my code

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getIssue(String issueKey) async {
final url = 'https://******.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/issue/$issueKey';

final response = await http.get(
  Uri.parse(url),
  headers: {
    'Authorization':
        'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$apiToken'))}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
);
print("${response.statusCode}");

print("${response.request}");

try {
  return jsonDecode(response.body);
} catch (e) {
  print("error is $e");
}


return jsonDecode(response.body);
```

}